# is it feasible to create 1 million folders for images for each user rather than saving image name in sql server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, windows, web-applications, social-networking

we are creating a Social Networking sites in ASP.NET 3.5 . We are creating user specific SlideShow for Images. Say for 1 million users, each user will save some images and right now we are saving the Image name in the DB.

So while fetching next image, we have to go first to DB then to the Image folder for the specific image and then send the response to the user.

Instead of that, if we create User specific folder and save images on that folders and then query the particular user folder to fetch images, will it be a practical solution OR should we stick to the traditional DB as said above?

Is it good to create 1 million folders in Web Application?

Which method is faster in fetching images (from Folder or From SQL Server)? (we are not saving images in database)

Thanking you.

Comment: or SQL 2012 FileStream if you can afford it :)

Comment: Don't save your image into database.

Comment: If you're creating that many folders I'd definitely consider cloud storage and a caching mechanism for the file system structure.

Comment: FileStream will work on SQL 2008 as well if that is what you are using.

Comment: Complementing the @DaveShaw comment... You could go for SQL Server 2008 (or 2012) and use the FileStream. It would help, but also work on some kind of caching to avoid hammering the Database.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your system to be scalable, your web application should not know how the images are physically stored, or the how the meta-datas of the images are stored.

With one million user storing images, your storage will need to be a subsystem. It will need transparent fail-over, caching strategies. Its internal logic should not be known from the other systems. This will allow you to tune it, to change it, to enhance it.

You should have two subsystems :

- one for handling images meta-datas, with a service interface for creating, updating and retrieving images meta-datas (owner/dates/tags/comments/...) You can use a DB of any kind to handle this. But other systems should just see a service.
- one for handling images binary streams (for storing streams, for retrieving streams given a file id) You can use anything you want there from a file system to a DB, or a cloud solution, it would certainly be a mix of these. As above, other systems should just see a service.

Anyway, to answer your question, having one million folders would be quite uneffective ( as would be one folder with one hundred million images) But if you hide it behind a service, you give yourself the time to find a better solution before you hit one million users )